# Can't compile GWT project with GWTQuery in Eclipse

Tags: gwt, gwtquery, gquery

I'm trying to start using GWTQuery in a GWT project.

- I've created sample GWT project in Eclipse
- Added gwtquery-1.3.2.jar
  into war/WEB-INF/lib
- Edited Myproject.gwt.xml (added <inherits name='com.google.gwt.query.Query'/>)

When I compile the project it writes a lot of deffered errors but at the end it comes with:

```
   Scanning for additional dependencies: jar:file:/C:/eclipseBacklog/Backlog/war/WEB-INF/lib/gwtquery-1.3.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/query/client/GQuery.java
      Computing all possible rebind results for 'com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery'
         Rebinding com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery
            Checking rule <replace-with class='com.google.gwt.query.client.impl.SelectorEngineNativeIE8'/>
               [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/eclipseBacklog/Backlog/war/WEB-INF/lib/gwtquery-1.3.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/query/client/Properties.java'
                  [ERROR] Line 20: The import com.google.gwt.core.shared cannot be resolved
                  [ERROR] Line 39: GWT cannot be resolved
               [ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery'
                  [ERROR] Hint: Previous compiler errors may have made this type unavailable
                  [ERROR] Hint: Check the inheritance chain from your module; it may not be inheriting a required module or a module may not be adding its source path entries properly
   [ERROR] Errors in 'jar:file:/C:/eclipseBacklog/Backlog/war/WEB-INF/lib/gwtquery-1.3.2.jar!/com/google/gwt/query/client/GQuery.java'
      [ERROR] Line 1483:  Failed to resolve 'com.google.gwt.query.client.GQuery' via deferred binding
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14214441/using-gwtquery-with-gwt

Comment: I don't use maven, I just created an Eclipse project, added gwtquery-1.3.2.jar into classpath and added "inherits" into Myproject.gwt.xml. I didn't found build.xml, so skiped this step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your version of gwt, you have to update to GWT-2.5.x. because this artifact of gquery has a undesired dependency of it. There are two `GWT.java` classes in 2.5, and gquery is depending of the new `com.google.gwt.core.shared` by mistake.

Open an issue at the gwtquery site becasuse this release should work with older gwt version as well.

You could also change the gquery version to 1.3.1 or 1.4.0-SNAPSHOT

**Update:** I've just [deprecated version 1.3.2](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Downloads), and released [1.3.3](http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/googlecode/gwtquery/gwtquery/1.3.3/gwtquery-1.3.3.jar) which compiles with previous gwt versions

Comment: Yes, you're right! I've changed gwtunit version to 1.3.1 and it works! Thank you very much!